# Authorize with curl and parse using simple html dom not working

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to read a html page using simple html dom for which an login authorization is needed.

for example: http://example.com/login/ is the login page and http://example.com/page/ is where i should parse the html.

So i used curl to do the login and simple html dom to parse.

But i dont know whether my page login or not, because when i display the response from curl its the login page contents!!

I searched through stack in allmost all related questions for many hours but i couldnt find what is going wrong.

below is my code

```
<?php
$curlPost['username']="username";
$curlPost['password']="pass";
$curlPost['token']="xxxxxxxxxx";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , "http://example.com/login/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
$response= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And the code to retrieve the html page

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , "http://example.com/page/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
$reponse= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
?>
```

Below is what i get in response in the top of my page:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   Date: Wed, 28 Jan 2015 06:59:44 GMT
>   Server: Apache
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Location: /login
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Wed, 28 Jan 2015 06:59:45 GMT
>   Server: Apache
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

followed by the login page html contents.

Anyone can advise me on what i'm doing wrong.

I'm running this in my localhost with the destination hosted in server.

And I didn't see any changes happening to "cookies.txt" file.

Many thanks.

Comment: Try setting the path of cookies.txt as absolute path like /var/www/app/cookies.txt and then set appropriate permission to cookies.txt. If the login is successful you may see some text in cookies.txt

Comment: I tried running by uploading to server but still no changes happening to cookies either.
p.s: followed the fullpath as u specified for the cookies.txt

Answer (score 0):

That looks like normal output to me. If you don't want the headers, don't set `CURLOPT_HEADER`

Comment: well, if it login then it must return contents of the http://example.com/page/ contents and not the http://exmple.com/login/ contents.

Comment: It sounds like you need to work on your question. Figure out what you're trying to ask first and make sure there is a (?) in it somewhere.

Comment: read second and third sentence, 

if it login successfully it must return the http://example.com/page/ contents and not the http://example.com/login/ page contents.

Comment: That's not a question. The telltale sign being the lack of a `?`. And no, things like 'what am I doing wrong?' don't count. Form a good question and you'll get an answer.

Comment: you comment looks silly, 
i have stated what i want(which is my requirement), what i did and what i m getting.
Also i have told that i don't know whether the script is logging in or not by checking the cookies.txt or from the output.
if you don't wanna help that's fine.i dont know how could i frame my question further

Comment: Ok, see i m trying to bring results for my online interview in which i'm stuck. Bcoz only if the script successfully login i can read the next page.
but now i think its not logging in successfully.
If anybody can PM me i can give you more detail and show you the realpage from where i need to access.

Comment: This is still not a question. Please read the guidelines for more clarification.